# reserved words (Where, from , and) in full text search query in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb, I am stucked on a issue :

Data is :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a956e0b78d363d37f6a2ec4"), 
    "fieldType" : "Enter Source", 
    "value" : "Delhi", 
    "catgeory" : "Generic", 
    "synonym" : [
        "origin name or code", 
        "from", 
        "enter source", 
        "from where", 
        "fro wher"
    ]
}
```

When I use this query

```
db.getCollection("Rules_DefaultValue").find(
{ 
    "synonym" : "from where"
});
```

I got correct result as expected

But when I use this query

```
db.getCollection("Rules_DefaultValue").find(
{ 
    "$text" : {
        "$search" : "where"
    }
});
```

I didn't got any result , So I changed it again

```
 db.getCollection("Rules_DefaultValue").find(
    { 
        "$text" : {
            "$search" : "wher"
        }
    });
```

and this time it worked.
So I came to a conclusion that "where" is reserve keyword and I can't use it as it is. So I tried with escape char :

```
"$search" : "\"where\""
```

but again I did'nt got the result.

same thing is happening with

```
and , from , *
```

Please help me on this , How can I make query with these words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words like `where` and `from` are considered as [stopwords](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt) in MongoDB. It means that when you create a text index those words are wiped out from the index since they appear very frequently in English while the point of FTS is to index some words that allow you to easily find the document you're looking for. To fix that you can create your text index specifying language to `none`, try:

```
db.getCollection("Rules_DefaultValue").createIndex(
    { synonym : "text" },
    { default_language: "none" }
)
```

Then your query should return the document mentioned in your post.